# Blockchain.info receive payments API

Tags: php, json, api, payment, bitcoin

I have been trying to figure out the bitcoin payment API for the last few days.  I am convinced that I have the code right.  I call the API:

https://blockchain.info/api/receive?method=create&cors=true&format=plain&address=1QJ2a7RYRUY8KRUfy2UchdD7iDXHNz8vxe&shared=false&callback=http%3A%2F%2Fbtctest.comuf.com%2F%3Frefer%3Dtest

and it works fine, even the callback test fire works fine.  But I never receive the bitcoins sent to the addresses.  HELP!

Comment: You are saying that when the BTC is received, the callbacks are fired, but the balance is still 0?

Comment: No, callback is NOT fired once bitcoins are received, in fact, nothing really happens at all.  The bitcoins just get stuck in the account, like here: 1LmbsP1u12PSPVnvv6oHYw4kxgkLf8DZUn

Comment: Next time, make sure you provide some code....

Comment: Our callback is fired but we did not receive payment on our mail wallet. here you can see https://blockchain.info/address/1GkihBMpFQZZ1bA6ivtEAhFFUuzkBuEMPX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.  I talked to Blockchain staff.  Apparently my test transfers were to small.  YOU NEED TO TRANSFER AT LEAST 0.001BTC.

In the future I recommend blockchain.info's wallet API, instead of its receive payments API.